# Вопрос по кэшированию

Tags: ruby-on-rails

На сайте есть динамичная главная страница и много статичных внутренних. Все страницы кэширую Кэшированием фрагмента. Но т.к. главная страница динамическая, хотелось бы удалять периодически кэш  только для главной страницы. Сейчас раз в час делаю Rails.cache.clear, но так удаляется вообще весь существующий кэш. Как очищать кэш только для главной страницы?

Comment: А какого рода динамика у вас на главной? Коллекция какая-нибудь?

Comment: да, выборка картинок из базы, с сортировкой. а на других страницах просто показ картинки в большом размере. Т.е. главная динамично меняет порядок сортировки картинок. Хочется чтобы час она висела в кэше, потом кэш удалялся и происходила выборка из базы и снова в кэш

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете писать кеш следующим образом:

```
Rails.cache.write('key', 'value', :time_to_idle => 60.seconds, :timeToLive => 600.seconds)
```

Для удаления можно использовать:

```
Rails.cache.delete('key')
```

Удаление нескольких айтемов:

```
Rails.cache.delete_if {|k, v| k =~ 'key' }
```

Решение похожей проблемы можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12005412/2546083)

Comment: где это писать? я пишу во вьюхе <% cache do %> ... <% end %>
кэширую фрагмент